# Canonical URL formatting issue causes Facebook to interpret mobile URL as a different URL

Tags: url, blogger, facebook-comments

I need to format this canonical URL and I cant figure out how! I've looked around the web and this site a lot and I've realized that I need a specific answer.

**Problem Description:**

1. My BLOG's desktop view has (say) URL: *www.x.com/page.html*
2. The same page in mobile view URL would be: *www.x.com/page.html?m=1*
3. Its all good and dandy to this point, but the problem comes when I use facebook comments with this. It parses url based on this: *www.x.com/page.html*

So, it is identifying **?m=1** in the end of the first URL as an entirely different URL.

i.e

- It is treating those two URL as ***different***
- Both of them are URL for the ***same*** page and I want them to be treated the same

Could anyone provide me a way to check if the loading page is **?m=1** and if it is **?m=1** then remove the **?m=1** when sending it to facebook?

**I WOULD GREATLY APPRECIATE IT IF THE SOLUTION IS INLINE** if it is *not inline*, oh well, I just need a solution right now.

*Current code snippet used is this:*

```
<fb:comments colorscheme='light' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:xid='data:post.id' height='110' width='560'/>
```

> **Let me break the question into small parts**(incase someone is not a native speaker and wants to help/learn about this problem)
>
> - I want to detect if the loading page has ?m=1 in its URL or not. The canonical URL for this is **data:post.url** applied as
>     **expr:href='data:post.url'**
> - If a **?m=1** is detected from **data:post.URL** , I want to remove it and send the remaining URL into **expr:href=** so that both my URLs
>     are identified the same when my website displays facebook comments.
>
> Click the image link below to look at this image please. This is the same URL but the
>   comments are being sent to me as if they're from different URLs. I
>   want them to appear under the same thread.
>   This is it--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7fK2.png

I haven't found this particular answer anywhere and I am hopeful that 
some creative solutions will pop out in this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
<fb:comments colorscheme='light' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:xid='data:post.id' height='110' width='560'/>
```

Use `data:post.canonicalUrl` instead of `data:post.url`

This is the Blogger's layout tag for getting the Canonical URL of a blog post (This will always default to the `blogspot.com` domain, so there won't be ccTLD issues as well)

Comment: That solved my problem perfectly! I knew I was missing something when I used that code. Since you are knowledgeable about this topic, may I also ask you for assistance on these problems?
(1)How to change the layout of Facebook's default comment box for mobile? (for example: I cant get the stickers and pic upload feature that is available in the desktop counterpart, with mobile). I've seen some sites customize their comment-box; which is the reason I think its possible.
(2)Do you any alternative to the mobile='only' attribute which is used to display widgets only in mobile on blogger?